# How to generate animated GIF of this manipulate with Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, animated-gif, beamer

This is my code representing a cycloid and I want to create an animated GIF of it. Atfer creating the GIF I want to include it into my beamer presentation.

```
 cicloida[tm_] := 
     Module[{a = 4, x, y, t, xx, yy, gridlinex, gridlinesy},
      x[t_] := a (t - Sin[t]); y[t_] := a (1 - Cos[t]);
      gridlinesx = Table[{xx, GrayLevel[.4]}, {xx, 0, 4 a Pi, aPi/4}];
      gridlinesy = Table[{yy, GrayLevel[.4]}, {yy, 0, 2 a, a/2}];
      ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tm},
       PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
       Epilog -> {Thick, Blue, Circle[a {tm, 1}, a], Red, 
         PointSize[Large], Point[{x[tm], y[tm]}],
         Black, PointSize[Large], Point[a {tm, 1}]},
           GridLines -> {gridlinesx, gridlinesy}, 
       Ticks -> {a Pi Range[4], a {1, 2}}, 
       PlotRange -> 2 a {{0, 3 Pi}, {0, 1}}]]
            Manipulate[
     Quiet@ cicloida[tm], {tm, .0001, 6 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
     SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass a list of graphics or any other expression to Export to create an animation in an "SWF", "AVI", "TIFF", or animated "GIF" file. Export will also create an animation instead of a list when given a Manipulate, Animate, or ListAnimate:

In[1]:= list = {Graphics3D[Cuboid[]], Graphics[Rectangle[]], 
                Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]], Graphics[Point[{0, 0}]]};
In[2]:= Export["animation.avi", list]
```

So this must work:

```
Export["animation.gif", Manipulate[ ... ]];
```